# How to install npm packages in localy?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, archlinux, manjaro

I am using Manajaro. I have installed node & npm from ARU. The problem is whenever I tried to install any npm package, it gets installed in the global folder means in my home dir. But I need the node folder and pacakge.json in the current local folder. I have tried most of the methods from the stack but didn't solve my problem. Hope to get some help from all the pros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fist run this command in your project

```
npm init
```

and follow all questions

then install any package there:

```
npm install -s jest
```

Comment: I did it earlier, It gave me some error- " Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.". Then I tried to give the repo link but doesn't work.

Comment: It is solved I have to finish my init then I have to install pkg. Thank you.

Comment: @isuro , great it helped :) can you please check the answer as a solution?